# how to count something in multiple columns in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to count items per person per date in google sheets. What formula do you recommend for?
I write this but it does not work:

```
=countifs(A2:A11, "3/14/2020", B2:B11, "person1", D2:H11, "*")
```

View image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Pivot table

Have a look at the attached spreadsheet
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/....](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tdoob8ktl2BWXMW9wjPOBaUdVlfOH6AHA1bHy1VfYkg/edit#gid=710978805)

[image: Google sheets Pivot table]

Please read more about how to create and use [Pivot Tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this by writing formulas?(without using pivot table)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the mmult method to get the row totals, then follow it with a grouping or pivot query:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:B11,mmult(n(D2:H11="*"),transpose(column(D2:H11)^0))},"select Col2,Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col2,Col1"))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:B11,mmult(n(D2:H11="*"),transpose(column(D2:H11)^0))},"select Col2,sum(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the range of first criteria is only one column, succeeding criteria should also use the same range, one column.

```
B2:B11, "person1", D2:D11, "*", E2:E11, "*" ...
```

reference: [Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the first range (criteria_range1 argument).](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/10/excel-countifs-multiple-criteria/)